# tab bar always appear in each view controller in IOS. How to fix that?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

Now I create a storyboard, its structure likes:

```
UITabBarController
|--UINavigationController
|   --UIViewControllerA
|      --UIViewControllerA0
|      --UIViewControllerA1
|      --UIViewControllerA2
|   
|--UIViewControllerB
```

I only need the `tab bar` appears at the bottom of `UIViewControllerA` and `UIViewControllerB`. But now the `tab bar` appears at the button of `UIViewControllerA`,`UIViewControllerA0`, `UIViewControllerA1` and `UIViewControllerB`.
Like this:
[image]
     [image: This is want I want]

[image]

The last two pictures is what I want.
However, when I enter `UIViewControllerA0` or `UIViewControllerA1` or `UIViewControllerA2`, they also have `tab bar` at the bottom.
[image]

I don't want the `tab bar` appear at the button of this view controller(`UIViewControllerA1`,`UIViewControllerA1`,`UIViewControllerA1`).
I haven't write any code for `UITabBarController`. Can this be fixed by storyboard ? Or do I need to fix it in code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This value can also be set from Storyboard for the ViewController(UIViewControllerA0,UIViewControllerA1,UIViewControllerA2):

[image]